Cannot execute: spark-submit
I’m trying to automate a PySpark code using Airflow  (i m using docker ) and I’m getting the following error:

This is the entire error msg in case it's not clear in the screenshot  :
[2024-05-30, 09:53:15 UTC] {spark_submit.py:401} INFO - Spark-Submit cmd: spark-submit --master spark://***-spark-master-1:7077 --name arrow-spark --deploy-mode cluster jobs/python/ETL.py
[2024-05-30, 09:53:15 UTC] {spark_submit.py:571} INFO - /home/***/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/bin/spark-class: line 71: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: No such file or directory
[2024-05-30, 09:53:15 UTC] {spark_submit.py:571} INFO - /home/***/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/bin/spark-class: line 97: CMD: bad array subscript
[2024-05-30, 09:53:16 UTC] {taskinstance.py:2698} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 433, in _execute_task
    result = execute_callable(context=context, **execute_callable_kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/apache/spark/operators/spark_submit.py", line 174, in execute
    self._hook.submit(self.application)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/apache/spark/hooks/spark_submit.py", line 502, in submit
    raise AirflowException(
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Cannot execute: spark-submit --master spark://***-spark-master-1:7077 --name arrow-spark --deploy-mode cluster jobs/python/ETL.py. Error code is: 1.
[2024-05-30, 09:53:16 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1138} INFO - Marking task as FAILED. dag_id=sparking_flow, task_id=python_job, execution_date=20240530T095308, start_date=20240530T095315, end_date=20240530T095316
[2024-05-30, 09:53:16 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:107} ERROR - Failed to execute job 1368 for task python_job (Cannot execute: spark-submit --master spark://***-spark-master-1:7077 --name arrow-spark --deploy-mode cluster jobs/python/ETL.py. Error code is: 1.; 73)
[2024-05-30, 09:53:16 UTC] {local_task_job_runner.py:234} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
[2024-05-30, 09:53:16 UTC] {taskinstance.py:3280} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check```

I already did the connection in airflow : 

[![enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/XvjI70cg.png)](https://i.sstatic.net/XvjI70cg.png)

This is my dag : 
```import airflow
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.providers.apache.spark.operators.spark_submit import SparkSubmitOperator

dag = DAG(
    dag_id = "sparking_flow",
    default_args = {
        "owner": "airflow",
        "start_date": airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(1)
    },
    schedule_interval = "@yearly"
)

start = PythonOperator(
    task_id="start",
    python_callable = lambda: print("Jobs started"),
    dag=dag
)

python_job = SparkSubmitOperator(
    task_id="python_job",
    conn_id="spark_default",
    application="jobs/python/ETL.py",
    dag=dag
)

end = PythonOperator(
    task_id="end",
    python_callable = lambda: print("completed successfully"),
    dag=dag
)

start >> python_job >> end

Can someone help me understand what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it?
Thanks!

What's the second line of the error message say, in its entirety? Mind you, someone will probably come along and point out that error messages shouldn't be included as screenshots, but rather as text.

Thanks for the feedback.  I'll rectify it

"/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: No such file or directory" seems pretty clear. Spark is written in Java, and even PySpark needs a JVM to actually be present to interact with it.
